# Return bool from platform method call

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

I've implemented code to that attempts to delete a screenshot after it has been taken. The user is given prompt asking them whether they'd like to delete the image.

I'm having trouble trying to figure out what I need to do in order to get a result back to flutter and perform a function based on that result.

Below is the native swift function:

```
func deleteLastTakenScreenshotFromLibrary() {
let fetchOptions: PHFetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
if (fetchResult.firstObject != nil) {
    let firstAsset: PHAsset = fetchResult.firstObject!
    let arrayToDelete = NSArray(object: firstAsset)
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges( {
        PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(arrayToDelete)},
         completionHandler: {success, error in print("Finished deleting asset. %@", (success ? "Success" : error!))
      }
    )
  }
}
```

That's being handled with a MethodChannel like this:

```
let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
let deleteLastScreenshot = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "/delete-screenshot",
binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)

deleteLastScreenshot.setMethodCallHandler(
  {
    (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {  
      self.deleteLastTakenScreenshotFromLibrary()
    }
  }
)
```

If the user deletes the screenshot I want to perform another native function but if they don't I want to perform a function in flutter.

If someone could help explain how to do this that would be amazing!

Comment: You're going to have to do this in two parts. One Dart->native method call to initiate the change, which as you notice tells you its result in the completion handler. In that handler, you'll need to perform a native->Dart method call with the result. (Note that you'll have to use `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }` within the completion handler to be sure to perform the native->Dart call on the main thread.) You can't just wait in Flutter for the native action to finish. (You might be tempted to instead use `performChangesAndWait`, but you may not call that on the main thread.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I don't suppose you'd be able to provide an answer with an example? I'm hoping to be able to perform a function if the allows the image to be deleted or if they don't.

Comment: Please look at the two repos [here](https://github.com/richardheap/audio_push) and [here](https://github.com/richardheap/audio_worklet). The first one is a good example of a plugin. The second build on the first by adding the native->Dart method call (but isn't as well polished). So, the second contains an example of triggering an action in iOS, and then, later, calling from iOS to Flutter. You could adapt that to pass your return result later.